# Echo command to write into a file works in terminal but fails in rc.local script

Tags: linux, shell, echo

I am trying to execute this rc.local script

```
sudo echo "m41t00 0x68" > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f804000.i2c/i2c-1/new_device
```

The response is:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# /etc/rc.local
+ sudo echo m41t00 0x68
echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

This works perfectly in the terminal. But fails in the script.

EDIT:
I tried changing the file permissions by chmod 777 on the file in question but it didn't help.

Comment: `sudo echo foo > bar` doesn't make sense. Keep in mind that the `> bar` happens **before** `sudo` or `echo` is run, so you aren't actually getting file permissions to write to a file you couldn't open otherwise. And you don't need permissions to *write* to a file descriptor you inherited pre-opened, so `sudo echo` has no effect at all.

Comment: That said, as for the failure at hand, I'd expect it to have more to do with boot order and whether the hardware referred to by that sysfs filename is actually ready (driver active, &c) at the time in question.

Comment: I assume you *don't* have the same problem if you're writing to a regular local file (not in `/sys`), right? That would make it no longer a question about the shell, and entirely a question about the specific file -- thus, about the i2c device, its driver, its configuration, how it's initialized, etc.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Agreed. I suspected file permissions. I did chmod 777 on the file to allow write from all users. That didn't help. Driver might be an issue. Since it is working fine in the terminal, I assumed it's fine.

Comment: Don't **ever** run `chmod 777` -- it makes something writable even by users that are explicitly used to run untrusted code, such as `nobody`. Under basically no circumstances (other than special cases like `/tmp`, which is protected by special rules for the sticky bit) will you ever need anything more permissive than `775`. And anyhow `rc.local` is run by root, and even beyond that, if it *were* a permissions problem as such it would fail during the `open()`, not during the `write()`.

Comment: ...so, it's quite certainly *not* a permissions problem, but overwhelmingly likely an issue specific to the device in question and (likely) its initialization state at the point in boot time at question. Which means that you've basically included effectively none of the relevant details, since we don't know that that device is, how and when it's initialized, or... well... anything else about it either.

Comment: As Charles has covered the root of the problem, I thought I would just add that by default init files are run as root, so the sudo is superfluous

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Device is m4t32 real time clock over I2C-1 bus connected on raspberry pi with Raspbian OS.

Comment: @grail Agreed. I was just trying to make it work somehow.

Comment: @EmbeddedManiac, have you considered using udev rules to trigger your script's invocation to happen only *after* the i2c drivers are done loading, instead of letting `rc.local` happen whenever it happens with no synchronization against other parts of the boot process? See https://gist.github.com/h0tw1r3/11191428/ for an example (the details there are around a different clock, but the generalities should hold).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. You are right. It was the driver loading problem. The appropriate RTC driver was not in place before execution of new_device command.. Just added few seconds delay and seems to work just fine..

Comment: tsk, tsk (re; the hardcoded-delay approach, which is really unnecessarily fragile). I rather strongly suggest the udev route, or *at least* having a wait/retry loop (so you can take advantage of faster initialization when available, and still recover if for some reason the hardware isn't ready at its usual time).